# Must the Notifications style be the one of BigTextStyle, BigPictureStyle, InboxStyle and MessagingStyle?

Tags: android, androidx

I'm learning Notifications, I use Android Studio 4.0 with latest androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat.

There is a sample code about [Notifications](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/Notifications) in the project user-interface-samples.

I find there are many differents about Notifications between this androidx and previous API.

Must the  Notifications style be the one of `BigTextStyleNotification`, `BigPictureStyleNotification`, `InboxStyleNotification` and `MessagingStyleNotification` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the notification styles available :

> Notification.BigPictureStyle, Notification.BigTextStyle,
> Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle, Notification.InboxStyle,
> Notification.MediaStyle, Notification.MessagingStyle

You can get more info on this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Style).

Just for information purposes, to create a notification without hustle and get all predefined formatting in one place, just do the following :

1. Go to the Project Tab of android studio and right click.
2. Click on New -> UI Component -> Notification
3. Enter the required notification name

To call this notification just enter the following :

```
<NotificationClassName>.createNotification(getApplicationContext());
```